Google Search not reading OpenGraph Meta Tags
Google Search seems to be displaying wrongfully my website's OpenGraph Meta Tags. I'm using Next.js (Pages) + Next-SEO (as using <Head> will pretty much repeat OpenGraph Tags from _app on subpages, and I don't want that). However, Google's crawler sometimes seems to be picking up the wrong information.
Issue 1 - Wrong Description & Image for Main Page
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
  <title>Where Is The Google Car</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <meta name="description" content="WhereIsTheGoogleCar is the largest community-driven database of Google Street View Sightings, monitoring since 2020.">
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Where Is The Google Car">
  <meta property="og:description" content="WhereIsTheGoogleCar is the largest community-driven database of Google Street View Sightings, monitoring since 2020.">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.whereisthegooglecar.com/about.webp">
  <meta property="og:image:alt" content="Where Is The Google Car">
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Where Is The Google Car">
  ...
</head>

By manually searching on Google my site through site:whereisthegooglecar.com, OpenGraph data seems to be shown properly, excluding og:image. That's weird.

Nonetheless, if we google the site normally without any filters, Google does NOT display OpenGraph data. Instead, it displays info from the most recent card from the front page.
In some cases it may display the image from og:image...

but in other cases, it uses the card image.

How can I enforce Google (or any other crawler) to ONLY pick up and show the OpenGraph Information from <head/>?
Issue 2 - Subpages not displaying OpenGraph Images
<head>
  ...
  <title>York, England, United Kingdom in Google Street View - WhereIsTheGoogleCar</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <meta name="description" content="Google Street View Car in York, England, United Kingdom on March 21, 2024.">
  <meta property="og:title" content="York, England, United Kingdom in Google Street View - WhereIsTheGoogleCar">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Google Street View Car in York, England, United Kingdom on March 21, 2024.">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.whereisthegooglecar.com/api/og?img=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whereisthegooglecar.com%2F_next%2Fimage%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fcdn.whereisthegooglecar.com%252Fimages%252F1220679133504209018.webp%26w%3D1920%26q%3D75">
  <meta property="og:image:alt" content="York, England, United Kingdom in Google Street View - WhereIsTheGoogleCar">
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Where Is The Google Car">
  ...
</head>

As this website is recently new (and has gone through two different domains), Google has only crawled one (out of 8k!) subpages.
Unfortunately the subpage image doesn't seem to be shown in Google Search...

although Google Images seems to show it.

I assume this may be because I'm generating OpenGraph Images on-demand using vercel/satori, but I'm not really that sure.
Issue 3 - Google Images crawling Main Page Cards, but not grabbing Alt Text
<div>
  <div data-radix-aspect-ratio-wrapper="" style="position: relative; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 56.25%;">
    <div class="relative bg-muted" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px;">
      <img 
          alt="Picture of a Google Car spotted in Sweden on April 16, 2024." 
          loading="lazy" 
          decoding="async" 
          data-nimg="fill" 
          class="rounded-md object-contain" 
          src="https://cdn.whereisthegooglecar.com/images/1229913881229393960.webp" 
          style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; inset: 0px; color: transparent; z-index: 1;"
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

This is a weird one, coming from my ignorance. Google Images' crawler picks up the most recent cards, but the title doesn't seem to match with the image (as the title is picked up from og:title, and not the card's alt itself)

Is there a way for Google Images' Crawler to pick up a different title for a specific image?

Please try putting
'<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">'

all preload image tags after meta tags.
